# Is there anything other than taxonomy and flagging out there for organising/describing/promoting content for better search and refinement?

Tags: search

I'm trying to make and get more out of the content on a site. So when someone adds a description, the topic/main points (which isn't the title of the node) are prioritised/promoted automatically somehow, or added in a sub-field. So that when people are searching the site, they can search the title ofcourse but main points of the nodes as well.

Instead of flagging content for keywords, definitions of what the content is about, or using taxonomy. Is there something else out there? The problem i'm having with flagging is I can't put them in to one view that people can filter (when exposed). I would have to create multiple flagging views covering every possible definition (I have over 20 flags and it just won't work like this).

On top of that, i'm interested in any other cool modules out there that may work with, or advance taxonomy or flagging or are their own thing I may not have heard of?

I also wanted users who sign up to the site to do most of the categorisation and defining of content.

Comment: For your kind information. You question is too broad, as you can see *your last three paragraph* are corresponds to  *three different requirement*. You can split them and can make separate questions. And asking for MODULE is not permitted on DA.

Comment: Hi codenext, Here is my question "Is there anything other than taxonomy and flagging out there for organising/describing/promoting content for better search and refinement?". I just gave descriptions of taxonomy and flagging in the content area just to clarify that I want to replace either of these with a different method if possible.